# Realm change-listener unintentional invoked

Tags: android, realm

Basically I have two models, Chat and Message. Chat contains a field of type RealmList with all messages that belong to the corresponding Chat. My Problem: When I try to add a Message "a" (which already exists inside the realm) to a Chat "b" ( --> code) a RealmChangeListener is called. The RealmChangeListener is listening on the whole Message-Table. The OrderedCollectionChangeSet is call with an array of changes, these changes contain all Messages contained within the messages field inside the Chat "b". My Question is if this is intended and why this is happing?

I tried to track down the problem by commenting out different lines. But in the end the ChangeListener is alway called when I add an Message to a Chat.

```
class Chat {
    ...
    val messages: RealmList<Message> = RealmList()
    ...
}

realm.executeTransaction {
    newMessage = realm.copyToRealm(aMessage)
    chat.messages.add(newMessage)
}

allMessage.addChangeListener { messages: RealmResults<Message>, 
    changes: OrderedCollectionChangeSet? -> 
    //Always invoked when above transaction runs
    //changes contains changes-Array with all Messages from above 
    chat
}

class Message {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + System.currentTimeMillis()
    var messageId: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var messageContent: FlatMessage? = null
    var user: User? = null
    var createdAt: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var updatedAt: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var chat: Chat? = null
    var isNew: Boolean = false
    var isEdited: Boolean = false
    var insertDate: Date = Date()
    var isBotMessage: Boolean = false
}
```

I expected the changeListener only to be called when a message is added to the messages table, not when an already existing message is added to a RealmList field of a chat.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us your `Message` class ?

Comment: I'm experimenting the same behavior

Comment: Same if listener is set on a RealmResults from a query or on a RealmList from an object

Comment: What exactly is `allMessage`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Its a RealmResult -> the whole Message table

Comment: @Maelig I have added the Message model. Now I noticed that I have a reference to Chat inside the Message-Model. Do you think that the Message-Table-Query could be notify because the RealmList<Message> inside chat inside the Message-Object changes. Thats a circular relation if I am right. Because Message depends on Chat and Chat depends on a list of Messages.

Comment: If A references a list of B and in B there is a reference to A, so every listener on A or B will be triggered if A or B is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue on github and got answers : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6401

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out and come back later.

Comment: Hey, if you are interested in a solution and the cause of my problem, look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

so in case anyone comes across this, I actually figured out the problem.

**Problem**

My message class has a field chat of type chat. Because of this there was a circular relationship.

**Let me explain:**

- We have a chat chatA.
- We have a message messageA -> Is already persisted inside the Message-Table, but yet not added to chatA.

We add messageA to chatA:

- Every message that belongs to chatA technically gets changed because:

  - chatA has a list of messages which just changed because we added a new message -> therefore chatA changed
  - chatA (which is inside a lot of messages) notifies the messages that a property inside them changed
  - finally the realmChangeListener gets called

**My solution:**

I just replaced the chat field of type Chat inside Message to a Long field chatId. I know it isn't a pretty solution. Feel free to suggest a better one.